# Wordpress excel download from plugin

Tags: php, excel, wordpress

I am making a wordpress plugin that collects information from the user and then presents it in an admin screen in a table. I would like to also be able to download this table to excel. I know how to do a basic download to excel file in PHP with this code:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

which then converts all of the page output to an excel file.

But in this case, I need to also be able to use wordpress functions like get_option(), which I can't use in just a straight called php file. But if I make it a wordpress admin page, the admin skin gets included in my file.

Anyone know how to do an excel download from the wordpress admin screen that includes info from wordpress functions like get_option?

Comment: How are you actually creating the Excel file... all you're saying here is that you know how to set http headers to con a browser into thinking it's getting an Excel file

Comment: An no-formatting html table. I need the page to be just the table, not any skin/formatting.

Comment: Why not a CSV file then, it's more honest sending the correct csv headings, and Excel has no problems when opening csv files

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear.

But, If you are talking about importing excel sheet of data into WordPress, then xl2wp is the ideal plug-in. It can import Title, post date, excerpt, tags, all in ONE SEO data, categories and custom fields.

you can find it here
http://xl2wp.sigmaNames.com